# Document an Express API POST method with routing-controllers-openapi

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, routing-controllers

I am using [routing-controllers-openapi](https://github.com/epiphone/routing-controllers-openapi) to document an API and I am facing a problem to show the body from a request as parameter in the Swagger UI.

The controller is implemented this way:

```
@HttpCode(201)
  @OpenAPI({
    description: 'Create a new user'
  })
  @Post('/')
  async newUserAccess(@Body() user: UserAccessDto): Promise<void> {
    await this.service.newUserAccess(user);
  }
}
```

The Swagger UI shows the UserAccessDto in the example from the parameters but not in the parameter, as de body:
[image]

I am trying to achieve something like this, in the Pet Store Swagger UI:
[image]

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Comment: Try using @BodyParams() instead of @Body()

Comment: I have tried, same behaviour in the Swagger UI.

Comment: Everything seems to be right. The difference in Swagger UI rendering is caused by OpenAPI version used for the API. Your API uses OpenAPI 3 where request bodies are defined as, well, request bodies. The second screenshot is for an OpenAPI 2.0 API where request bodies were defined as body parameters (but the idea is the same - it's the request body, just named differently). Compare that with the OpenAPI 3.0 Petstore version: https://petstore3.swagger.io/ - where request bodies are displayed just like in your API.

Comment: @Helen thanks for the explanation! I took a look at the link you sent and everything seems to be right! []s